# Perl how to extrapolate part of a word in a string

Tags: perl

Let's say I have the following string in a text file:

```
hello my name is /yellow/duck
```

I'm wondering if there's a function that you can run on that string and return "*yellow*".

I know Perl has a wildcard variable `.` but I'm not sure if it's applicable here since to my limited knowledge, you can only attribute words to the `.`.

Comment: Successful computer programming requires precise thinking, and a specification like *"how can I get `yellow` from this string"* is pretty much useless. A good analyst will guess that you probably want the text between the slashes, but we shouldn't be analysing requirements on Stack Overflow: you should be able to say properly what you want. You also need to think about what happens if there are more than two slashes in the string, or just one, or none at all. We can't help you with any of this; only you know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I know perl (sic) has a wildcard variable `.`

Perl has no such "wildcard variable". You might be referring to the meaning of a `.` in a regex pattern:

> `.`       Matches any single character except a newline (unless `/s` is used)

which is documented in `perldoc perlre`.

*Prima facie* your question makes no sense. But, reading between the lines, you seem to be asking if there is a way to match any sequence of characters between two `/` characters.

```perl
my $x = "hello my name is /yellow/duck";
if ($x =~ m{/ ( [^/]+ ) /}x) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

You can understand that regex match by reading `perldoc perlre` on your computer. See also `perldoc perlreref` and `perldoc perlretut`.

You cannot a learn programming without studying. One of the major advantages of Perl compared to other languages is the immense amount useful documentation included with the distribution. You should read all of it at least once, and refer back to it at every opportunity. See `perldoc perltoc`.

Having a [decent book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049517.do) does not hurt either.

Comment: *Learning Perl 7th Ed.* still teaches calling subroutines using the ampersand notation: *"You invoke a subroutine from within an expression by using the subroutine name (with the ampersand)"* (page 62) and then *unteaches* it later on. I think this was Randal's idea. It has caused so many problems for me with people still coding using the Perl 4.0 style that I cannot recommend it. I learned Perl from *Programming Perl 2nd Ed.* but I like to learn everything at once and that may not suit everybody.

Comment: I reviewed the 7th edition, and I did not think there was anything wrong with the way they went about it. It's a progression. Initially, they teach Perl as it if is BASIC and progress from there.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there's a function that you can run on that string and return "yellow".

```
my $s = 'hello my name is /yellow/duck';

print func($s), "\n";

sub func { 'yellow' }
```

Yes, this "answer" is facetious, but it has some serious and significant points

- You must be absolutely precise when specifying, implementing, and documenting software. It is nothing like ordinary human language
- Just because a program produces the "right result" it doesn't mean that it is correct